# find files with path of a directory exclude subdirectories

Tags: find

How can I use `find` to traverse a directory, but not recurse into its subdirectories?

I tried `-prune` and it does not work. And there is no `-maxdepth` option.

```
find /opt/projectname/bin -type f /opt/projectname/bin -prune -o -print
find: missing conjunction
```

```
/opt/projectname/bin/file_1_is_printed
/opt/projectname/bin/file_2_is_printed
/opt/projectname/bin/directory_within_bin/some_file_should_not_be_printed
/opt/projectname/bin/directory_2_within_bin/some_file_2_should_not_be_printed

/usr/bin/find:
         find.c $Date: 2011/08/12 15:04:36 $Revision: r11.31/4 PATCH_11.31 (PHCO_42158)
         libcpio.c $Date: 2008/05/27 16:08:10 $Revision: r11.31/2 PATCH_11.31 (PHCO_36666)
         $Revision: @(#) find R11.31_BL2011_0923_2 PATCH_11.31 PHCO_42158
```

This question is not a repeat question. There is no GNU here. Although the question may be a repeat question, the answers posted on those questions ask installations of GNU tools. Hence if the answers here help solve, this is a unique thread.

Comment: "I tried prune and it does not work." Please [edit] your question and show us the exact command that you tried (anonymizing file and directory names).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error “missing conjunction” is because you repeated the directory name after `-type f`, and `find` doesn't know how to parse that.

To avoid traversing subdirectories, you need to prune directories, not regular files. However, you must not prune the starting directory, otherwise `find` will process nothing but it. An easy way of recognizing the starting directory is to arrange for its name to be `.`.

```
find /opt/projectname/bin/. -name . -o -type d -prune -o -print
```

Explanation:

- `-name .` — if the name is `.`, [do nothing]
- otherwise: `-type d` — if the file is a directory, don't descend into it
- otherwise: print the path

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your `find` command in the Question is actually what you typed, you've mixed actions with the directory search roots, leading to the error message.

I've based my suggestion on [this man page for HP UX `find`](http://ods.com.ua/win/eng/unix/usail/man/hpux/find.1.html), which tallies with your "*no `-maxdepth`*" statement.

Try this variant instead:

```
find /opt/projectname/bin -path '/opt/projectname/bin/*/*' -prune -o -type f -print
```

I'd actually consider this "cleaner" alternative if I knew there weren't "too many" files in the directory, but it may not be acceptable to you in your situation:

```
find /opt/projectname/bin/* -type f -print -o -prune
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this, today, and it took a lot of investigation and testing but I came up with a solution that *does **not** require you to specify each individual subdirectory that you need to ignore* (*NOTE* that, in the following, the `dir-name` *can* be `.`.)

```
$ find  dir-name/*  -name file-name  -print  -o -prune
```

If you need to find a `.` file, such as `.login`, then the command should be ...

```
$ find  dir-name/.*  -name .file-name  -print  -o -prune
```

If you need to `-exec` something, such as to delete the file(s) found, then this for-do loop seems necessary:

```
$ for  FILE  in  $( find  dir-name/*  -name file-name  -print  -o -prune )
do
    echo  "Removing  $FILE"
    rm  -f  $FILE
done
```

**Oh**:  This is specifically for Korn-shell in HP-UX-11.31

It's not needed in Linux, which has much-easier syntax for avoiding the subdirectories.  This might work also in other Nix variations that are not Linux, besides HP-UX, but I have tested only HP-UX.

Comment: [Bash pitfall number 1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). Use `-exec`.

Answer (score -2):

```
find ${INP_PATH} -type f -ls | grep -v "${INP_PATH}/.*/"
```

Comment: i do not get it