# Exclude all subdirectories from find

Tags: find, directory

I want to look into a folder for some files but I do not want to look into any subdirectories.

I do not want to exclude a directory but **All**!

I have tried this [from](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190547/find-files-with-path-of-a-directory-exclude-subdirectories)

```
find "$dir" -name '*.out' -type d -prune
```

but the results is the results are nothing. Any help?

Comment: try `-maxdepth 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try looking at the manual?

The option you are looking for is `-maxdepth`, as @StevenPenny already wrote.

One reason why results are nothing is (from the manual)

> If the whole expression contains no actions other than -prune or -print, -print is performed on all files for which the whole expression is true.

So as your options include `-prune`, there is no implicit `-print`. Your command would only prune directories named `*.out`.

If you really want to use `-prune`, do this:

```
find "$dir"/* -type d -prune -o -name '*.out' -print
```

Note that this uses `"$dir"/*`, because `"$dir"` is a directory and would be pruned. This negates the advantage of `find` that it is not limited by the maximal argument length

Comment: By using `"$dir"/*` as the starting point, you would miss any hidden names in the `$dir` directory.

Answer (score 10):

The simplest way to acomplish that task (find files in a folder excluding all subdirectories) would be

> `find $dir -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.out' -o '.*.out'`

as @StevenPenny and @RalfFriedlal have wrote the maxdepth option is what you are looking for.

From find manual:
-maxdepth levels
              Descend at most levels (a non-negative integer) levels of directories below the starting-points.  -maxdepth 0
               means only apply the tests and actions to the starting-points themselves.

`-type f`   : You are searching for regular files
`-name '*.out' -o '.*.out'`   : the -o means or and allows you to include in your search eventuali hidden files with the extension .out.

Sorry for my bad english :(

Comment: `find` would find hidden files without you having to do anything special.

Comment: @Kusalanda: Sorry, you are right, my fault. There is not need to use -o '*.*.out'

Answer (score 3):

It seems as if you don't actually need `find` at all here.

```
for pathname in "$dir"/*.out; do
    [ ! -f "$pathname" ] && continue

    # do whatever you need to do to "$pathname" here
done
```

After the `-f` test, `"$pathname"` would point to a regular file or a symbolic link to a regular file. Note that hidden files would be skipped as `*` does not match filenames starting with a dot (unless the `dotglob` shell option is set in `bash`, which you may or may not be using).

With `find`:

```
find "$dir" -mindepth 1 -type d -prune -o -type f -name '*.out' -print
```

The `-mindepth 1` causes the starting directory to not get pruned by `-type d -prune`.  The `-print` should be replaced with the action that you would want to take on the found pathnames (which will be of regular files that has names ending with `.out`).

Or,

```
find "$dir" ! -path "$dir" -type d -prune -o -type f -name '*.out' -print
```

This only uses standard `find` options and prunes all directories that are not the same as the starting path.

Alternatively,

```
find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.out' -print
```

Using `-maxdepth 1` would, more simply, stop `find` from descending into any of the start directory's subdirectories.

The `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth` options, although commonly available, are extensions to [the standard `find` command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/find.html), and if your implementation of `find` does not have them, you would have to go with the shell loop or the `find` alternative that uses `-prune` only (with `-path`).

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
printf '%s\n' $dir/*.out(^/)  # files of any type except directory (excluding
                              # hidden ones)
printf '%s\n' $dir/*.out(-^/) # same but also excludes symlinks to directories
printf '%s\n' $dir/*.out(.)   # regular files only (excluding hidden ones)
printf '%s\n' $dir/*.out(-.)  # regular files or symlinks to regular files
                              # (excluding hidden ones)
printf '%s\n' $dir/*.out(D-.) # same, but include hidden ones.
```